# SonarQube 5 Treemap for rule compliance is missing

Tags: sonarqube, heatmap, treemap, sonarqube-5.0

Since upgrading to SonarQube 5, the treemap in dashboard is changed! It used to be rule compliance, it is now switched to coverage!

How can I configure so that I can show a treemap for all projects for rule compliance in dash board again?

For Color Metric, I do not see a "Rule Compliance", I only see a "Security Rule Compliance" which is not what I want. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This became a separate plug-in called Issue Density. Once instsalled this plug-in the treemap is back. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Density+Plugin